# Set USD as default Currency In CCAVENUE

Tags: php, ccavenue

I have by default INR as my set currency for payments. I want to receive the payments in dollars. How can I set dollars as my default currency.

I am using the PHP api for implementing the CCAVENUE PAYMENT GATEWAY. Everything is done . I just need to set the dollar as my default currency.

```
<form method="POST" name="customerData" action="ccavRequestHandler.php">
        <table width="40%" height="100" border='1' align="center"><caption><font size="4" color="blue"><b>Integration Kit</b></font></caption></table>
            <table width="50%" height="100" border='1' align="center">
                <tr>
                    <td>Parameter Name:</td><td>Parameter Value:</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2"> Compulsory information</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>TID :</td><td><input type="text" name="tid" id="tid" readonly /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Merchant Id :</td><td><input type="text" name="merchant_id" value=""/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Order Id    :</td><td><input type="text" name="order_id" value="123654789"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Amount  :</td><td><input type="text" name="amount" value="10.00"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Currency    :</td><td><input type="text" name="currency" value="USD"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Redirect URL    :</td><td><input type="text" name="redirect_url" value="http://localhost/ccavResponseHandler.php"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Cancel URL  :</td><td><input type="text" name="cancel_url" value="http://localhost/ccavResponseHandler.php"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Language    :</td><td><input type="text" name="language" value="EN"/></td>
                </tr>
```

I changed the currency from INR to USD but its not working and gives me an error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out the answer myself. Their was a bug from the ccavenue side. They fixed it and now INR and USD are working